# about MATLAB fscanf

Tags: matlab, scanf

I'm MATLAB biginer for studying about bigdata.

I received a assignment data file(.txt) from my LAB, it shows traffic amount of an area for every 10minutes.

Thus, the elements of the matrix that represent amount of traffic for a month is 4464.[6(every 10minutes)*24(hrs)*31(days)]

And there are 80000 of these type of matrix.

Then total number of element is 4464*80000, but it overs memory limitation of MATLAB.

So I need to load 4464*4000 matrix from the data file.(1/20)

suppose that file name is 'data.txt', I did like this,

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%d %f', [4464*4000]);
fclose(fid);
```

however I failed to load the file and matrix.

the result is like below

```
fid = 3
A = [48;0]
```

I don't know what is the problem.

And How can I load total data file through this method?

Thank you ~

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data file that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner I suggest you to use 'Select Text File Data Using Import Tool'

"1). On the Home tab, in the Variable section, click Import Data. 
(or)
2). Alternatively, right-click the name of the file in the Current Folder browser and select Import Data."

Then Import Tool opens, In Imported Data section, select how you want data to be imported.

After Importing you can cross check whether all your data is imported successfully by scrolling down window :)

If you need more information, Please check the link

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-data-interactively.html